# Is my meal & workout plan suitable for losing fat and gaining muscles?

Tags: muscle, workout, food

The below list is not exactly how I usually eat but approximately correct. Furthermore, I've used calories calculator to check their calories just to help you give me better recommendation. In addition, I've included my body detail below.

---

It is how I ate today, and I generally eat like this everyday.
Breakfast
Chicken breast, 2 big pieces: 300
Brown Rice, 1 cup : 220
some vegies: 20

Lunch
Low Fat Greek Yogurt: 80
Chicken breast, 2 big pieces: 300
Instant Noodles, 1/2 package: 200

Dinner
Brown Rice: 220
Garden Vegie Soup: 80

Snacks:
Whey protein, 1 scoop: 100kcal
Mandarine, large: 80 kcal

conclusion
cals: 1500 +- 100
protein: 188g
carb: not sure.

---

Body detail
weight: 74KG
height: 177cm

---

workouts (4 days a week)
weight lifting: 1.5 hour
cardio: 0.5 hour (stepper)

---

Am I eating correctly? I want to lose weight (also gain muscles) but it seems like I'm gaining weight and I'm not sure whether I am gaining muscles or not. By the way, it's been only a week since I have started eating this way and working out. Are there any manipulation done in my meal or workout plan? Do I need to eat more calories than this?

Comment: These type of questions are open to debate, opinion etc. Hence they are not suitable for the Stack Exchange Q&A style. I suggest you check some online forum were you can get multiple opinions on the topic or even better ask someone who has relevant knowledge (example given someone who is a dietitian and not just an "internet guru" with many forum posts etc).

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like you already answered your own question. You're gaining weight so that's good, so the obvious question is are you gaining fat? if yes cut down a little if not then see how it goes over the next couple of weeks.

I would advise buying Franco Columbu Body building nutrition or Winning Bodybuilding, they have all you need to know about eating right.

Here's a sample diet from his book for non-competitive bodybuilder training 1-2 hours, 3-6 times per week.

**Breakfast:**
3 eggs
1 slice bread
1 serving fruit
Water / coffee

**Lunch:**
1/2 Chicken
1 baked potato
1 slice bread
1 glass beer

OR

Steak 
Small serving of spaghetti
Small glass of wine

OR

Chicken
Brown Rice
Vegetables
1 Slice Bread
1 Glass of beer

**Snacks**
Fruit, nuts, seeds

**Dinner**
Fish
Vegetables
Large Salad
glass of water

Tip: don't eat carbs late on because less food gets absorbed later in the day

Only you can know what's right for you as we are all very different but it's a good starting point, I can't stress enough though if you're serious buy a book written by a pro.